# Making a dictionary of images

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know I asked this before, but I'm still not sure why I only get the date in the list now instead of the location, date, and caption in the list when I test this. Can anyone please help me fix this? The end result is supposed to look like this.

```
{filename: [location, date, caption]}
```

I got this

```
{'images/skating.jpg': {'East York Arena': ['2014.11.03']}, 
'images/sunglasses.jpg': {'High Park': ['2013.02.03']}, 
'images/skating2.jpg': {'East York Arena': ['2014.11.03']}}
```

Here is the file.

```
images/skating.jpg,East York Arena,2014.11.03,Shea skating.,skating,Shea,boy
images/sunglasses.jpg,High Park,2013.02.03,Cool guy.,Shea,sunglasses,happy
images/skating2.jpg,East York Arena,2014.11.03,Shea skating 
again!,skating,Shea

def create_image_dict(open_csv_file):
'''(file) -> dict of {str: list of str}

The open csv file has the format:
filename,location,date,caption,keywords,keywords, ...
Return a dictionary with key filename and values [location, date, caption]
'''
d = {}
for line in open_csv_file:
    info = line.split(',')
    filename = info[0]
    location = info[1]
    date = info[2]
    caption = info[3]
    if location not in d:
        d[filename] = {location:{date: caption}}
return d
```

Comment: what is your output ?

Comment: {'images/skating.jpg': {'East York Arena': ['2014.11.03']}, 'images/sunglasses.jpg': {'High Park': ['2013.02.03']}, 'images/skating2.jpg': {'East York Arena': ['2014.11.03']}}.

Comment: off-topic, but note that you probably want a dictionary of tuple values, rather than list values. Lists should generally be homogenous and order should have little meaning. Tuples are heterogenous and order is meaning. Your data is clearly the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is exactly what you told Python to do here:

```
  d[filename] = {location:{date: caption}}
```

so replace it by this:

```
d[filename] = [location,date,caption]
```

Comment: @JohnAnderson huh? Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Scharette's answer appropriately points out the core error here, that `{filename:
 {location: {date: caption}}}` is a dict of dict of dicts, rather than your requested dict of lists (`{filename: [location, date, caption]}`), but I wanted to comment briefly about your code in general.

First of all, you're using a comma-separated format in your file, so use the stdlib module specifically designed to handle those files -- `csv`.

```
import csv

with open("filename.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

Reader objects are iterables of iterables, representing lines -> fields. This makes it easy to do:

```
    # from above
    for line in reader:
        fname, location, date, caption = line[:4]
```

the slice `[:4]` here doesn't grab the first four characters of `line`, it operates over the first four comma-separated fields, so your last sample line becomes

```
fname = 'images/skating2.jpg'
location = 'East York Arena'
date = '2014.11.03'
caption = 'Shea skating again!'
```

You can actually wrap this all in a dictionary comprehension, too.

```
with open("filename.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    result = {fname: (location, date, caption) for line in reader
              for fname, location, date, caption in line[:4]}
```

Comment: @bigd cool, then neglect the `open` call. It doesn't change the `csv.reader` call though :)

Comment: Also, don't we have to split it first before doing the [:4]?

Comment: @bigd no, did you read the answer? I spent a lot of time talking about how `csv.reader` objects operate on fields, and ***specifically*** say "the slice `[:4]` here doesn't grab the first four characters of `line`, it operates over the first four comma-separated fields."

Comment: But if I don't split it, I get i m a g when I test it

Comment: @bigd I can't replicate those results. Looks like you haven't read my answer or my code completely, and likely have missed the `reader = csv.reader(f)` line, which was essentially the whole point of my answer. Please spend some more time reading the information I'm giving you before you comment again.